# What's the meaning that the sentence expressed?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> This story begins in 1997. I was a professional musician, age
>   twenty-seven. I was making a full-time living just playing
>   music—playing lots of gigs around the U.S. and Europe, producing
>   people’s records, playing on people’s records, and running a little
>   recording studio.I was even the musician and MC for a circus.
>
> My bank account was always low, but never empty. I made enough money
>   to buy a house in Woodstock, New York.***I was living a musician’s dream***.

The above paragraph is from the book *Anything you want by Derek Sivers* page4. As for the bold sentence in the paragraph, I'm not sure how to understand its meaning is the more appropriate way.

1, That means that the author was living a life which he dreamed of his being a musician.

2, It means that the author's dream of being a musician had come true already.

Which one of my understanding is correct？Or they may be all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your first guess is close, but not quite there.

"A musician's dream" means "the ideal life that a musician would want to have".  If you were a musician, what would you want your life to entail?  It would mean you would play lots of music, help other people with their music, etc. - exactly what the author states in the first paragraph that you quoted.

It's not what that particular person had dreamed of being in the past - in that case, they would have said "I was living the life I had dreamed."

"Living a profession's dream" means "living the ideal life of a profession."